# Security of threshold blind signatures

Tags: cr.crypto-security

To prove unforgeability of threshold signatures TSig =(TKeyGen, TSign, Verify), it is sufficient to prove that the underlying signature scheme Sig=(KeyGen, Sign, Verify)
is secure and TSig is simulatable.
My question is what's the intuition behind defining the security of threshold blind signatures the same way, and is it applicable for signatures on committed messages.

Comment: it might be helpful if you gave a reference (for the specific paper(s) it seems you have in mind).

Comment: @daniel, here is a reference [Provably Secure Blind Threshold Signatures Based on Discrete Logarithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.8000&rep=rep1&type=pdf).